# PowerShell Invoke-Command severe performance issues

Tags: powershell, scripting, remote-access

I'm having a heck of a time running a script on a remote system efficiently. When run locally the command takes 20 seconds. When run using `Invoke-Command` the command takes 10 or 15 minutes - even when the "remote" computer is my local machine.

Can someone explain to me the difference between these two commands and why Invoke-Command takes SO much longer?

Run locally on MACHINE:`get-childitem C:\ -Filter *.pst -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Run remotely on \MACHINE (behaves the same rather MACHINE is my local machine or a remote machine: `invoke-command -ComputerName MACHINE -ScriptBlock {get-childitem C:\ -Filter *.pst -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}`

Note: The command returns 5 file objects

EDIT: I think part of the problem may be reparse points. When run locally `get-childitem` (and `DIR /a-l`) do not follow junction points. When run remotely they do, even if I use the `-attributes !ReparsePoint` switch)

EDIT2: Yet, if I run the command `invoke-command -ComputerName MACHINE -ScriptBlock {get-childitem C:\ -Attributes !ReparsePoint -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}` I don't see the Junction Points (i.e. Documents and Settings). So, it is clear that both `DIR /a-l` and `get-childitem -attributes !ReparsePoint` do not prevent it from recursing in to a reparse point. Instead it appears to only filter the actual entry itself.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: `-Recurse -Path C:\` This is your problem.  You are iterating over ALL the objects in your entire drive.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 how is that different locally vs remotely? Appleoddity -
 Are you really not passing any credentials to invoke-command? I imagine the remote connection has admin rights and therefore has to see and search through more folders than the local one, but that's still a big difference.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - That is intentional. Locally it takes 20 seconds on an SSD. Remotely it takes 10 minutes or longer.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Those are the exact commands I am running from a Powershell ISE window. My account is a domain admin. I do notice that get-childitem run via invoke-command follows junction points (i.e. documents and settings) whereas get-childitem run locally gives errors (without the silentlycontinue switch) when it hits a junction point. Could that be a cause?

Comment: @Appleoddity Is your ISE process launched as admin?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the issue is the Reparse Points. For some reason, access is denied to reparse points (like `Documents and Settings`) when the command is run locally. Once the command is run remotely, both `DIR` and `Get-ChildItem` will recurse into reparse points.

Using the `-Attributes !ReparsePoint` for `get-childitem` and the `/a-l` switch for `DIR` does not prevent this. Instead, it appears those switches only prevent the reparse point from appearing in the file listing output, but it does not prevent the command from recursing into those folders.

Instead I had to write a recursive script and do the directory recursion myself. It's a little bit slower on my machine. Instead of around 20 seconds locally, it took about 1 minute. Remotely it took closer to 2 minutes.

Here is the code I used:
EDIT: With all the problems with PowerShell 2.0, PowerShell remoting, and memory usage of the original code, I had to update my code as shown below.

```
function RecurseFolder($path) {

    $files=@()

    $directory = @(get-childitem $path -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select FullName,Attributes | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -like "*directory*" -and $_.Attributes -notlike "*reparsepoint*"})
    foreach ($folder in $directory) { $files+=@(RecurseFolder($folder.FullName)) }

    $files+=@(get-childitem $path -Filter "*.pst" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Attributes -notlike "*directory*" -and $_.Attributes -notlike "*reparsepoint*"})

    $files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a large directory structure and you just need the full path names of the files you should be able to speed that up considerably by using to the legacy `dir` command instead of `Get-ChildItem`:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName MACHINE -ScriptBlock {cmd /c dir c:\*.pst /s /b /a-d /a-l}
```

Comment: This gave me hope, but I tried it and I got the same results. See my comment above about junction points. I see the same behavior with `dir`. Run remotely it follows junction points and I have a feeling there is some kind of loop or something. Any thoughts on why this happens or how to avoid it. It needs to be compatible with PS 2.0.

Comment: This dir command has a switch for reparse points.  I added /a-l to the command which hopefully would skip those, but I can't promise that will fix it.

Comment: It's really strange. The command you provide is right but it still follows the reparse points. Same thing happens if I use get-childitem with the -attributes !ReparsePoint switch in PS 3+.

Comment: Afraid I don't have an explanation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a remote session:

```
$yourLoginName = 'loginname'
$server        = 'tagetserver'
$t = New-PSSession $server -Authentication CredSSP -Credential (Get-Credential $yourLoginName)
cls
"$(get-date) - Start"
$r = Invoke-Command -Session $t -ScriptBlock{[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles('c:\','*.pst','AllDirectories')}
"$(get-date) - Finish"
```

Comment: I changed `-authentication` to `Kerberos` because I don't have `CredSSP` enabled. The script block works but it still enumerates Reparse Points and takes an excessive amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
It is obvious that Powershell has problems with the transfer of arrays through PSRemoting.

It demonstrates this little experiment (**UPDATED**):

```
$session = New-PSSession localhost

$arrayLen = 1024000
Measure-Command{
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host ("Preparing test array {0} elements length..." -f $using:arrayLen)
    $global:result = [Byte[]]::new($using:arrayLen)
    [System.Random]::new().NextBytes($result)
  }
} |% {Write-Host ("Completed in {0} sec`n" -f $_.TotalSeconds)}

Measure-Command{
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host ("Transfer array ({0})" -f $using:arrayLen)
    return $result
  } | Out-Null
} |% {Write-Host ("Completed in {0} sec`n" -f $_.TotalSeconds)}

Measure-Command{
  Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Host ("Transfer same array nested in a single object")
    return @{array = $result}
  } 
} |% {Write-Host ("Completed in {0} sec`n" -f $_.TotalSeconds)}
```

And my output (time in ms):

```
Preparing test array 1024000 elements length...
Completed in 0.0211385 sec

Transfer array (1024000)
Completed in 48.0192142 sec

Transfer same array nested in a single object
Completed in 0.0990711 sec
```

As you can see, the array is tranfered more than a minute.
Single objects transfered in a few seconds despite their size